# Pandas DataFrame Name after pivot

Tags: python, pandas

After pivoting a DataFrame on a column, the returned DataFrame has that column's name in the upper left (see below, where df2 has 'b' in the upper left cell of the table).

**Question:**  How is this name accessed directly or changed?

I could rename column b before doing the pivot or unstack the pivot, rename the column and stack again.  However, I'm looking for a simple attribute which I can't seem to find.

One would think that df2.name would return this value, but that leads to:
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'`. Also, df2.info() doesn't reveal anything useful either.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'b': ['C', 'D', 'C', 'D'], 'val': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
df2 = df.pivot(index='a', columns='b', values='val')
>>> df2
b   C   D
a       
A   1   2
B   3   4

>>> df2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 2 entries, A to B
Data columns (total 2 columns):
C    2 non-null int64
D    2 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df2.columns` and `df2.index` have a settable `name` attribute:

```
In [65]: df2
Out[65]: 
b  C  D
a      
A  1  2
B  3  4

In [66]: df2.columns.name = 'foo'

In [67]: df2.index.name = 'bar'

In [68]: df2
Out[68]: 
foo  C  D
bar      
A    1  2
B    3  4
```

The column and row indexes also have a `names` (plural) attribute, which is especially useful when the indexes are MultiIndex. Each `names` attribute is a FrozenList, whose elements correspond to the names for each level of the MultiIndex. You can use it for setting single-level index names too:

```
In [70]: df2.columns.names = ['baz']

In [72]: df2.index.names = ['qux']

In [73]: df2
Out[73]: 
baz  C  D
qux      
A    1  2
B    3  4
```

Comment: I was aware that the index had a name attribute, but didn't know columns did as well.  Thanks.